# Bootstrap Collapse - Toggle class on click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've been doing some Google searches for the most efficient way to do this, but I have not found a working answer to it yet. I found   [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/twitter-bootstrap/teUoAR1nV7w) but it wasn't working when I tried it out.

I'm trying to toggle a class on click to the element 'a.accordion-toggle'. While the solution above did in fact work, it would toggle the class for every instance of 'a.accordion-toggle'. Since there are multiple accordions, this is not ideal.

Is there a way for me to target only the child of the accordion being clicked?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your selector, specify a [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/). This is the second argument to the jQuery.

$('a.accordion-toggle', '#theelementinwhichyouwanttosearch')